# how to change window background opacity with xlib?

Tags: background, opacity, xlib

How to change window background opacity with xlib ? But dont change window foreground. Compositor have run and XServer support 32 depth and TrueColor.

I have tried this:

```
unsigned long opacity = (unsigned long)(0x8ffffffful);
Atom NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY", False);
XChangeProperty(display, win, NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY, XA_CARDINAL, 32, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *)&opacity, 1L);
```

But it will change both background and foreground. I have also tried this:

```
unsigned long opacity = (unsigned long)(0x8ffffffful);
XSetWindowAttributes attr;
attr.colormap = new_colormap;
attr.background_pixel = opacity;
XChangeWindowAtrributes(display, win, CWColormap | CWBackPixel, &attr);
```

But it report BadMatch error. I think it have different Visual.

So how to change window background opacity with xlib ?

Comment: How do you get your visual and how do you create your color map? It's clearly that there is a mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a composite manager, then setting the color value of the background pixel should be sufficient. You have to make sure to have a `TrueColor`, 32-bit visual.

The window manager hint `NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY` sets the overall transparency of the window (that would include everything within the window), so basically after all rendering has been done, every pixel gets multiplied by the opacity value.

The following example looks for a 32-bit visual and creates a semi transparent window (by only setting the background pixel).

**e.g.**

```
#include <X11/X.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);    //default display
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(dpy); //default root window

    //visual info

    XVisualInfo vinfo;
    XMatchVisualInfo(
        dpy,                //display
        DefaultScreen(dpy), //default screen
        32,                 //32-bit depth
        TrueColor,          //class
        &vinfo              //a valid visual on success
    ); //don't forget to check the result!
    
    //window attributes

    XSetWindowAttributes xattr;
    xattr.background_pixel  = 0x7f7f7f7f; //normally you'd have to use 
                                          //the color shift masks of the visual
                                          //for our simple example, 
                                          //we set all values to 0.5
    xattr.background_pixmap = None;
    xattr.border_pixel      = 0;
    xattr.colormap          = XCreateColormap(dpy, root, vinfo.visual, AllocNone);

    long xattr_mask = (
        CWBackPixmap  |
        CWBackPixel   |
        CWBorderPixel |
        CWColormap
    );

    //window

    Window win = XCreateWindow(
        dpy,               //display
        root,              //root window
        0, 0,              //pos
        640, 480,          //size
        0,                 //border
        32,                //depth
        InputOutput,       //class
        vinfo.visual,      //visual
        xattr_mask, &xattr //attributes
    );
    XMapWindow(dpy, win);

    while (1) {
        XEvent evt;
        XNextEvent(dpy, &evt);
    }

    //cleanup

    XDestroyWindow(dpy, win);
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know how to create a semi transparent window. But I mean change the background opacity of an existing window which is created by others.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you should have said _"How to change the background opacity of **other** windows"_, then it would have been much clearer. Well, if you get a `BadMatch` error, that either means the window is `InputOnly` (make sure to have the right window) or what i suspect, not the right visual. Try to set a 32-bit visual (`TrueColor`), related colormap and clear the contents (`XClearWindow`) for a repaint. Maybe you want to query the attributes first (`XGetWindowAttributes`) to check what you're dealing with.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you set the background-pixmap to `None` (not only the color).

Answer (score 0):

I can change background like this now:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

XEvent ev;
XVisualInfo vi;
Display *disp;
int screen;
Colormap cm;
Window root;

Window create_win(Window parent, int x, int y, int w, int h, unsigned long bg_pixel)
{
    XSetWindowAttributes attr =
    {
        .colormap=cm, .border_pixel=0, .background_pixel=bg_pixel, // at least set those 3 members
        .override_redirect=True, // tell WM ignore it
    };

    return XCreateWindow(disp, parent, x, y, w, h, 0, vi.depth, InputOutput,
        vi.visual, CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWBackPixel | CWOverrideRedirect, &attr);
}

void update_win_bg(Window win, unsigned long color)
{
    XSetWindowBackground(disp, win, color);
    XClearWindow(disp, win);
}

int main(void)
{
    if(!(disp=XOpenDisplay(NULL)))
        return 1;
    screen=DefaultScreen(disp);
    if(!XMatchVisualInfo(disp, screen, 32, TrueColor, &vi))
        return 1;
    root=DefaultRootWindow(disp),
    cm=XCreateColormap(disp, root, vi.visual, AllocNone);

    Window frame=create_win(root, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0x0fff0000L),
           win=create_win(frame, 0, 25, 100, 50, 0x5f00ff00);

    XSelectInput(disp, frame, ButtonPressMask);
    XMapWindow(disp, frame);
    XMapSubwindows(disp, frame);
    XDrawString(disp, win, XCreateGC(disp, win, 0, NULL), 25, 25, "test", 4);

    while(!XNextEvent(disp, &ev))
         if(ev.type == ButtonPress)
             update_win_bg(frame, 0x8f0000ff);
    return (0);
}
```

But i "can not" change background for many windows such as lxterminal. I dont know why background color will cover its text and window restore the original background color when the text is exposed.